# Is $\neg (A\land B)= (\neg A \land \neg B)$ valid in Boolean algebra?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

Is this a valid operation in Boolean algebra?
$$
\neg (A\land B) \land C = (\neg A \land \neg B)\land C
$$

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, but maybe the fact this could be checked with a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) led someone to think the question was low-effort, although you might not have known that technique.

Comment: No; a simple truth table will help. See [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Formal_notation).

Comment: @J.G. It was downvoted because OP didn't show any of his work/progress on the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's $\neg(A\land B)=\neg A\lor\neg B$. Similarly, $\neg(A\lor B)=\neg A\land\neg B$. These are called [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).